# Redirect to UI-Route after Login Successfully

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

How to redirect to Home Page after Login successful,

I am using UI-router and below is my ui-router code.

```
var myrouting=angular.module('routingDemoApp', ['ui.router'])
myrouting.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("", "/index")

$stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "/index",
            templateUrl: "../Views/home.html"
        })
        .state('contactus', {
            url: "/contactus",
            templateUrl: "../Views/contactus.html",

        })

         .state('home', {
             url: "/home",
             templateUrl: "../Views/home.html",
         })
         .state('myModal', {
             url: "/myModal",
             templateUrl: "../Views/SignInPage.html",
         })

}]);
```

I have a button element calling ng-click='login function' for validation Username and Password. once credentials are valid i want to redirect a page to "Home.html"

**How to call ui-route after successfully login in below function?**

```
var mymodule2 = angular.module('module2', []);
mymodule2.controller('controller2', function ($scope) {

    $scope.loginFunction = function () {
        alert("Login");
        if ($scope.username == 'abcd' && $scope.password == 'hello123') {
            console.log('Login sucessfull');  
            ***// Redirect to Home Page.***

        }
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `$state.go("home");` like this, where the "home" is the state name where you would like to go:

```
var mymodule2 = angular.module('module2', []);
mymodule2.controller('controller2', function ($scope, $state) {

$scope.loginFunction = function () {
  alert("Login");
    if ($scope.username == 'abcd' && $scope.password == 'hello123') {
      console.log('Login sucessfull');  
      $state.go("home");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go("home");

```
var mymodule2 = angular.module('module2', []);
mymodule2.controller('controller2', function ($scope) {

    $scope.loginFunction = function () {
        alert("Login");
        if ($scope.username == 'abcd' && $scope.password == 'hello123') {
            console.log('Login sucessfull');
           // add $state.go here  
            $state.go("home);
        }
    }
 });
```